# Property 'HEIGHT' does not exist on type 'NamedExoticComponent<StackHeaderProps>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to use Header.HEIGHT from react-navigation-stack for the react-navigation header height calculation but as soon as I upgraded my react-native version from 0.59 to 0.61, I am getting some linting issues on typescript

issue: Property 'HEIGHT' does not exist on type 'NamedExoticComponent'
issue in code: const headerHeight = Header.HEIGHT

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I had the same issues with typescript I had to shift to JS

Comment: @RizwanAtta - I am using typescript for my whole application